# JavaScript SlideUp/SlideDown making my footer jumpy after slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me clarify where the problem is in my code.

I want to hide an element and then slideup, so the other element below it becomes visible (show) - same thing goes for slidedown.

Actually it works but it makes my footer jumpy everytime it slides, what is the solution?

```
var openF = $('.openForm').css('color', '#FFF');
$('#contact').hide();

$(openF).live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Open Contact Form") {
        $(this).val("Close Contact Form");
        $('#contactDT').slideUp(200);
        $('#contact').show(200);
    } else {
        $(this).val("Open Contact Form");
        $('#contactDT').slideDown(200);
        $('#contact').hide(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: No need for `$(openF)` - `openF` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Linking to an external site with your code is not helpful for SO as a Q&A platform. Try to include relevant code in your question.

Comment: Guido I did include the code above to the slide event that makes my footer jumpy, I thought looking at the source file might help faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem without seeing the HTML and CSS, but it sounds like you might have padding on the element that you are animating.

When you run your animations, they occur by continually updating the CSS height of the element.  The problem is if you have padding on your element, it will skip at the end of the hide animation.  (This is because even with 0 height, your element will still be the height of your padding.)

The solution for this is to apply your padding to some element inside a wrapper, where the animation will occur on the wrapper.

Comment: Alright, please review it from here. http://www.charlesmudy.com/work/charlesmudy/

Comment: I see. Did you see the contact page button and how the footer jumps when clicked? Its seems to be fine on about page. Am very confused.

Comment: No, the page shows up completely unstyled as your CSS file is being blocked by my work proxy.  If you can setup a JSFiddle demo, I could look there; otherwise, somebody else without restricted Internet can hopefully confirm.

Comment: OK have a look a here: http://jsfiddle.net/shina/ze9GG/   it seems to work fine here without problems. Maybe I'll wait for someone to check the main web link. Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are animating both on slideUp/slideDown and show/hide with 200 milliseconds each. That is why the jumpy effect. Don't pass the value `200` to show/hide functions.

Change this...

```
if ($(this).val() == "Open Contact Form") {
    $(this).val("Close Contact Form");
    $('#contactDT').slideUp(200);
    $('#contact').show(200);
} else {
    $(this).val("Open Contact Form");
    $('#contactDT').slideDown(200);
    $('#contact').hide(200);
}
```

to...

```
if ($(this).val() == "Open Contact Form") {
    $(this).val("Close Contact Form");
    $('#contactDT').slideUp(200);
    $('#contact').show();
} else {
    $(this).val("Open Contact Form");
    $('#contactDT').slideDown(200);
    $('#contact').hide();
}
```

This should get rid of the jumpy issue.

Comment: Thanks Neo108 but it didn't solve it ... can the problem be from my CSS? ... I have also ready several issues about SlideDown jumpy..

Comment: I replicated the issue on my PC and it worked when I did what I suggested. Perhaps I am not understanding your question correctly. Do you want the footer to stay fixed while the contact form is opening/closing? That is the height of the content section will be the same regardless of the contact form being open or closed?

Comment: Yes exactly ... am using height 100% and min-height 100% for my content. I do not have anything for my footer. I want it to stretch down while open and resize when closed. Now .. it just keeps bouncing somehow when resizing. See from here: www.charlesmudy.com/work/charlesmudy/contact.php

Comment: Ok. I am not able to replicate the jumpiness of the footer after I do the above change I suggested. The only other suggestion I would give is to wrap the contact form in a div with id `contact` and show/hide the div. See [http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/nbwTU/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/nbwTU/3/).